# how to get title name in url instated of id using node js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want the title of the post in the URL but i am getting id, URL: `http://localhost:8080/post/6108f14dc0ea6d1dd4e51a6f3`

but I want to like this:
`http://localhost:8080/post/example-post`

I am using node js and MongoDB in the backend

Comment: Are you calling this url from some external source (such as front end) ?

Comment: yes ,I am creating a blog website and I am calling specific posts, from MongoDB

Comment: In that case you're calling your url with an id instead of post name...

Comment: This needs to be changed from the place you're calling this api, not at the server